# Lower bound for probability of birth-death process at 0

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory, stationary-processes, steady-state

Consider a birth-death process with birth transition rate of 1 and death transition rate of $r + \gamma$ at every state $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Can we come up with an lower bound efor the steady-state probability of being at 0?

Comment: Assuming $\gamma\geq 0$, you can just bound $r+\gamma\geq r$ and get $\pi_0\geq e^{-1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 yes, I’m looking for a tighter bound though. Since $\gamma$ could be much larger than 1